# VS2019 - Sgen error Cannot implicitly convert type. Known Issue?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I have a project that successfully builds in both Release and Debug mode when targeting Framework 4.0. However, when I try to target Framework 4.8 the project will build in Debug mode, but when attempting to build in release mode I receive a large number of exceptions:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'X[][]' to 'X[]' produced by sgen.exe.

It seems to be related to a 'known issue' discussed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/system-center/orchestrator/unable-generate-temporary-class

The second and third workarounds seem to revolve around modifying the wsdl file which I do not have access/control/influence over.

So, that leaves the first workaround... But I am not certain how to use that work around.
The WSDL application is not producing an exception, the SGen application is.

Also... why does this issue not occur when targeting framework 4.0?

Comment: Not sure if [runtime changes for migration from .NET Framework 4.0 to 4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.0-4.8#xml-xslt) will cause this problem. Consider reporting it on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=61&entry=problem)